# По паспорту или с паспортом

Tags: предлоги

"Предполагалось, что новые правила обязывают граждан Украины совершать въезд в Россию не по внутренним, как раньше, а сугубо по заграничным паспортам."

Есть мнение, что подобные операции совершают не по документам, а с документами. Подскажите, какой вариант более корректный.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Более корректный вариант – "по документам". Можно въехать по заграничному паспорту и с внутренним (в кармане лежит).

Comment: Спасибо за ответ. Я тоже так чувствую, но найти грамотное объяснение нигде не могу.

Comment: Можно посмотреть значение предлога "по" на грамота.ру. Там примерно 20 значений, что-нибудь  должно подойти :)

Comment: ...9. Употр. при обозначении предмета, посредством которого или при помощи которого совершается действие. Учится читать по букварю. Передавать приказ по цепочке. Сигнал по азбуке Морзе. Отправить по почте. Говорить по телефону. Передать по радио. Ориентироваться по компасу.
Похоже на то. Спасибо за подсказку!